# how yo access item key in swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, url

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://mysit.com") {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        data, response, error in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let data = data, error == nil,
            let valueEncoding = response?.textEncodingName,
            let getContent = String(data: data, encoding: valueEncoding.textEncodingToStringEncoding)
            else { return }
        print(getContent)

        }.resume()
}
```

---

### my Data

```
{"Regions":null,"Cities":[{"Id":"9605","Name":"YANBAA AS SENAYAH"},{"Id":"15","Name":"ABHA"},{"Id":"13","Name":"AD DAMMAM"},{"Id":"1542","Name":"AL BAHA"},{"Id":"14","Name":"AL MADINAH AL MUNAWWARAH"},{"Id":"2213","Name":"AR'AR"},{"Id":"11","Name":"BURAYDAH"},{"Id":"10","Name":"HAIL"},{"Id":"17","Name":"JAZAN"},{"Id":"6","Name":"MAKKAH AL MUKARRAMAH"},{"Id":"3417","Name":"NAJRAN"},{"Id":"3","Name":"RIYADH"},{"Id":"2237","Name":"SAKAKA"},{"Id":"1","Name":"TABUK"},
```

---

how to get an array list of values "Name" ,can you help me?

Comment: Show your JSONDecoder code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
struct Root :Decodable{

    let Cities:[InnerItem]

}

struct InnerItem :Decodable{

    let Id:String

    let Name:String

}

do {

    let arr = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)

    print(arr.Cities)
}
catch {

    print(error)
}
```

//

**Note :**  This is the correct json structure

> {"Regions":null,"Cities":[{"Id":"9605","Name":"YANBAA AS SENAYAH"},{"Id":"15","Name":"ABHA"},{"Id":"13","Name":"AD DAMMAM"},{"Id":"1542","Name":"AL BAHA"},{"Id":"14","Name":"AL MADINAH AL MUNAWWARAH"},{"Id":"2213","Name":"AR'AR"},{"Id":"11","Name":"BURAYDAH"},{"Id":"10","Name":"HAIL"},{"Id":"17","Name":"JAZAN"},{"Id":"6","Name":"MAKKAH AL MUKARRAMAH"},{"Id":"3417","Name":"NAJRAN"},{"Id":"3","Name":"RIYADH"},{"Id":"2237","Name":"SAKAKA"},{"Id":"1","Name":"TABUK"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Together with the decoding step. I added several guards to print an error if one comes up. It is generally good practice to throw the error and handle it on the appropriate level.

```
func work() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://mysit.com") else {
        fatalError("url is nil.")
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            fatalError("\(error!)")
        }
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            response.statusCode == 200 else {
            fatalError("Response is nil.")
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            fatalError("data is nil.")
        }

        decode(data: data)

    }.resume()
}

func decode(data: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder.init()
    let welcome = try! decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: data)

    print(welcome.cities.first!)
}
```

The decoding helpers. `enum CodingKeys` are used to convert the lowercase attributes to the uppercase JSON attributes and back.

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    var regions: [Region]?
    let cities: [City]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case regions = "Regions"
        case cities = "Cities"
    }
}

struct City: Codable {
    let id, name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "Id"
        case name = "Name"
    }
}

struct Region: Codable {
    let id, name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "Id"
        case name = "Name"
    }
}
```

Some use services like [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io) to convert JSON strings to the specific programming language. It makes things faster and simpler.

Comment: fetch data from url JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
let responseData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: (response["Cities"] as! String).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, options: []) as! [[String: Any]]

for item in responseData{
  let name =  item["Name"] as! String
}
```